# MySQL Row Count on a long query

Tags: mysql, count

i'm trying to get out a COUNT() from the result of this query:

```
SELECT COUNT
  (SELECT *
   FROM `products` AS P
   INNER JOIN `aste` AS A ON P.id_asta = A.id_asta
   INNER JOIN aste_i18n AS B ON A.id_asta = B.id_asta
   WHERE id_fallimento = 284
     AND B.lang = 'it_IT')
```

How can i do this?

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the result of your query as a derived table and perform a `COUNT` operation on it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT P.id_asta 
      FROM `products` AS P 
      INNER JOIN `aste` AS A  ON P.id_asta = A.id_asta 
      INNER JOIN aste_i18n AS B ON A.id_asta = B.id_asta 
      WHERE id_fallimento = 284  AND B.lang = 'it_IT') AS t
```

Comment: @Giorgios Betsos ok i'm trying to understand why it report me the error " #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id_asta'".

Comment: @MarcoFacc Does your real query look *exactly* the same as the query above?

Comment: @Giorgios Betsos yes it does. It's very strange because the first query works good but at the same time the result show me three "id_asta" columns without report me the error "duplicate column name 'id_asta'".

Comment: @MarcoFacc Please check the edit I made. You just need to select one field, then `COUNT`. There was a confusion due to `P.id_asta`, `A.id_asta` fields having the same name.